# Do all SKUs of Windows 7 include 64 bit install discs?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I know both Ultimate and Professional SKUs include both 32 and 64 bit install discs, but I'm not sure about the Home Premium SKU. Can anyone verify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not always,

If you are purchasing OEM you have to be specific, both edition (Home premium, Professional, ultimate) and platform (x86 and x64).

If purchasing an Upgrade or Full edition, it comes with both x86 and x64 DVD's

That being said, it is only one serial key and you are licensed to use it on either.

Answer (score 3):

List of all available SKUs and editions (taken from my own MSDN premium subscription):

- Windows 7 Enterprise (x64) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Enterprise (x86) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Enterprise N (x64) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Enterprise N (x86) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Home Basic (x86) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Home Premium (x64) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Home Premium (x86) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Home Premium N (x64) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Home Premium N (x86) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Professional (x64) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Professional (x86) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Professional N (x64) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Professional N (x86) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Starter (x86) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Starter N (x86) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Ultimate (x64) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Ultimate (x86) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Ultimate N (x64) - DVD
  (English)
- Windows 7 Ultimate N (x86) - DVD
  (English)

The N editions are editions targeted at the European Market and do not include Windows Media Player.

The only 2 SKUs not including a 64-bit version are thus **Home Basic** and **Starter**.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart Home Basic does include 64 bit.

Comment: It is unlisted on my available downloads list and always was. I do see here and there a mention tho this version. But it's not available under the MSDN subscriptions page... which can only mean it's not available anywhere.

Comment: If you purchase Home Premium through http://www.win741.com/, you have to choose whether you want 32-bit or 64-bit. You don't get both.

Comment: So that's what the N means.  I've wondered (just not hard enough to look it up).

Answer (score 2):

I just received Windows 7 Home Premium Upgrade today and I can confirm both 32 and 64-bit discs.

Also, check out the Comparison Chart for Windows 7 Editions on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart).